# Average sum based on condition

Tags: postgresql, average

I have this table and datasample in a Postgres database

```
CREATE TABLE testAAA(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, datum date, COLA text, COLB text, COLC text, COLD int);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(1,to_date('01/01/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPA','1');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(2,to_date('01/02/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPA','1');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(3,to_date('01/03/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPA','1');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(4,null,'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPA','1');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(5,to_date('01/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPA','5');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(6,to_date('01/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPA','10');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(7,to_date('01/11/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORB','OPA','50');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(8,to_date('01/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPA','10');
INSERT INTO testAAA VALUES(9,to_date('01/11/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),'PLANTA','VENDORA','OPB','5');
COMMIT;
```

I'm trying to make a average sum based on condition and combination:

```
SELECT COLA,COLB,COLC,
CASE
  WHEN (datum >= now() - interval '6 month') THEN SUM(COLD)/6
  ELSE '0'
END AS datum_range
FROM testAAA
group by COLA,COLB,COLC;
```

My goal is to generate the last 6 months average on COLD colum using as combination COLA+COLB+COLC, if DATE interval condition is satisfied, skipping null value.

Right now I'm getting this error:

```
Error(s), warning(s):

42803: column "testaaa.datum" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How do I fix the above error?

Comment: Please add an expected output for your input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f04756660ff8e02fd92d90033b04e159)

```
SELECT *,
    SUM(COLD) FILTER (WHERE datum >= now() - interval '6 month') OVER (PARTITION BY COLA, COLB, COLC) / 6.0 as avg
FROM testAAA
```

The result:

```
| id |      datum |   cola |    colb | colc | cold |                avg |
|----|------------|--------|---------|------|------|--------------------|
|  1 | 2018-01-01 | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA |    1 |  4.166666666666667 |
|  2 | 2018-02-01 | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA |    1 |  4.166666666666667 |
|  3 | 2018-03-01 | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA |    1 |  4.166666666666667 |
|  4 |     (null) | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA |    1 |  4.166666666666667 |
|  5 | 2018-10-01 | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA |    5 |  4.166666666666667 |
|  6 | 2018-10-01 | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA |   10 |  4.166666666666667 |
|  8 | 2018-10-01 | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA |   10 |  4.166666666666667 |
|  9 | 2018-11-01 | PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPB |    5 | 0.8333333333333334 |
|  7 | 2018-11-01 | PLANTA | VENDORB |  OPA |   50 |  8.333333333333334 |
```

[demo: db<>fiddle][4]

1. Using a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) `SUM(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` allows you to do the SUM aggregation like within a `GROUP` clause but holding the original rows. The aggregation is added as separate column.
2. `FILTER` clause allows you to filter the input for aggregation functions. So you are able to aggregate only the rows with `datum >= ...`

Comment: Thx, but if I want to keep the avg as output in all the 9 records of the source table?

Comment: @user3925023 Expanded the answer

Comment: Thx, but my expectation is to see for all those record havin PLANTA | VENDORA |  OPA the AVG = 4.83

Comment: 4.83 was my fault, it is 4.16667 of course. But for your case you just have to remove the CASE. Appended answer. Please provide the expected output in your question next time. Then you will get the right answers much faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just move the condition to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT   cola, colb, colc, SUM(cold) / 6
FROM     testAAA
WHERE    datum >= NOW() - INTERVAL '6 MONTH' 
GROUP BY cola, colb, colc
```

Comment: I need to keep all record, if I do so I remove ones where the condition is not valid